# Limiting the size of a json string while maintaining validity

Tags: php, arrays, json, storage

My particular use case is for logging HTTP request parameters, responses and headers. I would like to be able to store only a part of the data without losing the structure of the data that does get stored.

So let's take the easy example, HTTP headers:

```php
const JSON_OPTIONS = JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE;

function limitSizeOfHeaders(array $headers, int $maxSize) {
  $currentSize = 0;
  $limited = [];
  foreach($headers as $name => $values) {
    $headerSize = strlen(json_encode([$name => $values], JSON_OPTIONS)) - 1;
    if(($currentSize + $headerSize) > $maxSize) {
      break;
    }
    $limited[$name] = $values;
    $currentSize += $headerSize;
  }

  return $limited;
}

echo "\n".json_encode(limitSizeOfHeaders([
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer aX93nd11a9a0asaZzt432rSAu',
  'Content-Type' => 'form/urlencoded',
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Cookie' => 'PHPSESSID=a9d78e29a2c150dee3'
], 120), JSON_OPTIONS|JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n\n";
```

which produces the output:

```json
{
    "Authorization": "Bearer aX93nd11a9a0asaZzt432rSAu",
    "Content-Type": "form/urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}
```

But headers have a very predictable structure. Each header is a property of an object that contains an array of one or more strings. A Json response body, might not be so simple. Even form data can be resolved as a multidimensional array of varying indeterminate depth.

So what I actually want is:

```php
function limitArraySize(array $anything): array
```

I think this is an interesting problem that someone else might have solved already.

Comment: I think you'd have to track the parsing stack yourself, and then you'd know how many unterminated layers you have when you hit your final length. Probably most of the time you'll have some wiggle room left to add terminators before you hit maxSize, or you can remove an element if not. But there's no way to avoid accounting for the output syntax in your own logic.

Comment: I’m not judging you, but I can’t think of a particular use-case for me where I want to log headers, and I’m either _not_ interested in all of them, or I’m _only_ interested in some of them but would find it acceptable to have a potentially truncated listed, without the knowledge that truncation happened.

Comment: @ChrisHaas headers was just an example. But I definitely want to log the response headers for any API request I make, up to a few thousand bytes, but I don't want it eating up all of my memory/hd space, same for any json response

Comment: If length is a concern, then why PRETTY_PRINT?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a bad idea of the data-corruption kind... with that said,

You could just keep removing the first deepest element until the encoding size fits. Note that getting the deepest element is tricky, but it can be solved with a recursive function:

```php
function limitArraySize(iterable $anything, int $max_length): iterable {
  $removeDeepest = function(iterable &$v)use(&$removeDeepest) {
    foreach($v as $key=>&$val) {
      if(!empty($val) && is_iterable($val)) {
        $removeDeepest($val);
        return;
      } else {
        unset($v[$key]);
        return;
      }
    }
  };
  for(;;) {
    $ret=json_encode(($anything));
    if(strlen($ret) < $max_length) {
      return $anything;
    }
    $removeDeepest($anything);
  }
}
```

Here, whenever `$removeDeepest` detect that it's not dealing with the deepest element, it will just keep calling itself 1 element deeper until it's at the deepest element and remove it.

```
echo json_encode(limitArraySize([
  'Authorization' => 'Bearer aX93nd11a9a0asaZzt432rSAu',
  'Content-Type' => 'form/urlencoded',
  'Accept' => 'application/json',
  'Cookie' => 'PHPSESSID=a9d78e29a2c150dee3'
], 120), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)."\n\n";
```

Prints:

```
{
    "Content-Type": "form\/urlencoded",
    "Accept": "application\/json",
    "Cookie": "PHPSESSID=a9d78e29a2c150dee3"
}
```

edit: scanning for the absolutely deepest element anywhere is difficult. this function should be *better* at it than the one above, but definitely not perfect (scanning for the absolutely deepest element is *difficult*, this is not the right way to do it, but it should get closer than the one above):

```
function limitArraySize(iterable $anything, int $max_length): iterable{
    $getDepthShit=function(iterable $v)use(&$getDepthShit):int{
        $ret=0;
        foreach($v as $val){
            ++$ret;
            if(is_iterable($val)){
                $ret+=$getDepthShit($val);
            }
        }
        return $ret;
    };
    $removeDeepest = function(iterable &$v)use(&$removeDeepest,&$getDepthShit){
        $deeperKey = null;
        $deeperDepth = 0;
        foreach($v as $key=>&$val){
            if(!empty($val) && is_iterable($val)){
                $depth=$getDepthShit($val);
                if($depth > $deepestDepth){
                    $deeperKey=$key;
                    $deeperDepth=$depth;
                }
            }
        }
        if($deeperKey!==null){
            $removeDeepest($v[$deeperKey]);
        }else{
            unset($v[$key]);
        }
    };
    for(;;){
        $ret=json_encode(($anything));
        if(strlen($ret) < $max_length){
            return $anything;
        }
        $removeDeepest($anything);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance this would appear to remove the deepest element descended from the first element rather than the deepest element overall. Consider: `['a'=>['b'=>['c'=>['d'=>'deep'],'e'=>'notsodeep']],'f'=>['g'=>['h'=>['i'=>['j'=>['k'=>['l'=>['m'=>'deepest']]]]]]]]` 'deep' and 'notsodeep' will be removed before 'deepest'. Actually it goes into an infinite loop due to some quirk of passing by reference. But even when I coax it to work it is a very inefficient solution since the entire input will be parsed with every limit failure. So while I thank you for answering, I wouldn't use this.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean with the data corruption comment. Obviously we will lose information, but the alternative is to just substr(json_encode($anything), 0, $max_length), which will definately corrupt my data. And since I'm logging hundreds of thousands of requests daily, storage is not infinate, and I don't implictly trust the servers that are responding saving the entire response is not feasible

Comment: @kaan_a ohh sorry i forgot an `&` throwing it into an infinite loop, replace `foreach($v as $key=>$val)`  with `foreach($v as $key=>&$val)` and try again, does it still go into an infinite loop?

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it

Comment: @kaan_a `At first glance this would appear to remove the deepest element descended from the first element rather than the deepest element overall` - that is correct. it's much easier to remove the deepest element descended from the first element than to actually detect the deepest element overall and remove that. it would be possible to scan for the absolutely deepest element, but that's much harder =/

Comment: @kaan_a made a smarter function that should be better at finding the deepest element anywhere, but it's definitely not perfect at it, it won't find the deepest key in every scenario, for example it would fail on `[[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[[["real deepest but confused because prevsion array has more overall members"]]]]`, here it would start removing numbers before removing the real deepest string..

Comment: `empty()` is inappropriate when a variable is guaranteed to be declared.  Please do not swear in your code on Stack Overflow.  If `return`ing in both outcomes of a condition block, then only return once AFTER the block.

Comment: @mickmackusa you're free to [improve the code](https://i.imgur.com/DEwQ8nr.png)

Comment: I don't like touching other dev's snippets.